# AngularJS form is undefined in $scope in controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to access a html defined form in the $scope in the controller. The thing is that the form is under ng-switch directive so I was suspecting this is the issue. Still, I couldn't find any solution to this.

My code is :

```
<div ng-switch="bla">
   <div ng-switch-when="blabla">
       <form name="myForm">
       </form>
    </div> 
</div>
```

And the js : `$scope.myForm` is returning *undefined*.

Can you please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it should be {{myForm}} when writing the scope variable on html page

Comment: @RakeshBurbure , I want to use it in a javascript file, not in the page.

Comment: js code please?

Comment: Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/PW2rQ/17/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right:
This directive creates new scope.
Like ng-if.
See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

Here could be an answer:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10944
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#ng-include

If you need the form in a method in the controller, that you call from the html code, you can use the form as a parameter.

For instance:

```
<form name="dataForm" ng-submit="$parent.processForm(dataForm)">
```

processForm is a method in the controller.
You need $parent here because of the child scope under ng-switch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that, but it still doesn't work, I can't figure out why...

Answer (score 0):

1. check that condition for div "ng-switch-when " is true i.e "blabla" is true or not . because form will be there only if the condition is true
2. If it is not working then try to declare form object in your controller (at the time when controller loads ). like this

$scope.myForm ={};

Hope it will work ........

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly, I still need the form object to apply some functions on it. If I define it like that, it will be a simple js object, and I cannot call setValidity for example.